# Get Endpoint HTTP verb/command attribute in middleware - .NET Core

Tags: c#, api, http, .net-core, endpoint

*Problem*: Given a .NET Core web API endpoint that looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> MyEndpoint () { }
```

**When a request is made, I want to be able to know *in all cases*, in the middleware layer, that the endpoint is defined as `[HttpPost]`.**

*Entire issue at hand:*

I want to add global error logging to every endpoint. So I decided to add some custom middleware.

```
public void Configure (IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  app.UseRouting();

  app.UseMyCustomLoggingMiddleware(); // my custom middleware

  app.UseCors();
  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseEndpoints();
}
```

In my custom middleware, **in the success case** I can easily check the endpoint verb/attribute using the `Endpoint` class.

```
public async Task InvokeAsync (HttpContext context)
{
  Endpoint endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();
  // endpoint.Metadata has the information i need! it knows it's a POST!
}
```

However, the **error case** is what I'm struggling with. `MyEndpoint` above is defined as a **[POST]** endpoint, so if someone attempts to make a **[GET]** request against it, I want to be able to log that error specifically. The same for other mismatched HTTP commands.

**But**, because we Configure our app to `app.UseRouting()`, in the ***error case***, when we use the incorrect HTTP command, the call to `Endpoint endpoint = context.GetEndpoint()` stops returning the actual `Endpoint` where we can access the metadata/verb (likely because it can't find it because of the mismatched HTTP verb\command), and instead returns an empty `Endpoint` object set to `{405 HTTP Method Not Supported}`.

If I register my custom middleware *before* the call to `app.UseRouting()` in an attempt to get the default routing to *not* automatically return `405`, then the `Endpoint endpoint = context.GetEndpoint()` call simply returns `null`, which is also bad.

**How can I get the fact that the target endpoint is defined as a [HttpPost] in *all* cases?**

I would like to avoid reflection if at all possible because I am logging high noise events and don't want to be hampering our performance.

Comment: See following on how to handle errors : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/overview/understanding-models-views-and-controllers-cs#understanding-controllers

Answer (score 0):

I would probably create two middlewares.

1. Error middleware
2. Logging middleware

Invalid requests will not pass the routing and you can hardly know the endpoint definition before it.

```cs
public void Configure (IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  // here you can handle the errors raised in the routing
  app.UseMyCustomErrorMiddleware(); 

  app.UseRouting();

  // log valid requests here
  app.UseMyCustomLoggingMiddleware();

  app.UseCors();
  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseEndpoints();
}
```